# Excel distance calculation by using Google Maps API key

Tags: excel, distance, calculation

I have been using this for couple of months without a problem. Now I am getting `#VALUE` in Excel all the time I try get the distance. What can be the problem?

I have Google Maps KEY `AIzaS.....I`

Request URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=$1&destinations=$2&mode=$3&key=$k

[image]

C8 = London, C9 = Manchester, C10 = Driving

Formula in C13: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(gmaps.distance.url;"$1";SUBSTITUTE(C8;" ";"+"));"$2";SUBSTITUTE(C9;" ";"+"));"$3";gmaps.travel.mode);"$k";gmaps.key)`

Response in C15: `=WEBSERVICE(C13)` **ERROR** `#VALUE`

Status in C16: `=FILTERXML(C15;"//status[1]")` **ERROR** `#VALUE`

Distance in C18: `=FILTERXML(C15;"//distance[1]/text")` **ERROR** `#VALUE`

Travel Time in C19: `=FILTERXML(C15;"//duration[1]/text")` **ERROR** `#VALUE`

If I copy-paste to my browser generated link in C13 I get data below on opened page. So API key and link working? Is there something wrong in `=WEBSERVICE(C13)` formula?

I have tried to use `=WEBSERVICE("GENERATED LINK IN C13")` with no success. Getting `#VALUE` as well.

While copy-pasting link from C13 to internet browser:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>London, UK</origin_address>
<destination_address>Manchester, UK</destination_address>
<row>
<element>
<status>OK</status>
<duration>
<value>14735</value>
<text>4 hours 6 mins</text>
</duration>
<distance>
<value>335534</value>
<text>336 km</text>
</distance>
</element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Comment: Which cell is showing the `#VALUE!` error?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post

Comment: I set up a Google API key and I cannot reproduce your problem.  (I copy/pasted your entries). And with C13 not showing an error, I can't really tell what the issue might be.  Changes in the list separator will cause that error, but that would affect C13.  An invalid API would give a `REQUEST DENIED` status message.  Something else is going on.  Perhaps upload a workbook demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try to check this at home as well, on home computer. However I don't understand how company can suddenly block such a feature? I mean block XML requests. I have also Currency Exchange Rate Excel that is requesting data from http:// XML and it works fine.

Comment: Perhaps your company is blocking access to that specific URL when generated in a certain way.  That would produce a non-error in C13, and VALUE errors in the other cells (as would an invalid url in c13)

Comment: It is also strange because if I copy generated link address from cell C13 and paste to my web browser then it works. If company would block URL completely it would give an error and not XML data?

Comment: I agree that it is strange, especially since I cannot reproduce it here.  That suggests something in your environment (excel workbook or company IT policy) that is blocking access to that website when generated by that particular workbook. If you can use the **same** workbook at home, whether it works or not will be useful information.  Also, see if you can access other web calls from within that workbook at work.

Comment: Ok. It works from my personal computer... There is no way to avoid company blocking? Strange that it worked on work computer for couple of months. Now they blocked it for some reason.

Comment: Probably best to check with your company IT department.