# Excel WEBSERVICE formula returns #VALUE error

Tags: excel, formula

This should be the strangest thing I have came across with MS Excel. I have very very very big calculation tool made with MS Excel. Now I wanted to increase it's functionality by adding distance and traveling time calculation using Google API Key. Everything worked fine until one day I started to get `#VALUE` errors.

I have started a [case earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959061/excel-distance-calculation-by-using-google-maps-api-key?noredirect=1#comment94765809_53959061) but now after some more investigations I have noticed a strange behavior. If I create new Excel workbook file on my work computer and use my Google Maps API key in `=WEBSERVICE` formula, everything works fine and I am able to get XML file data. However in my original calculation tool I receive `#VALUE` error. Also I have tried for example `=WEBSERVICE("https://www.google.com/")`. In newly created Excel workbook I get html code but in my calculation tool I get `#VALUE` error. I have tried to rename my file and copy to OneDrive with no success. I have also tried to remove all data queries and all vba macros with no results.

Of course I can create new Excel workbook and copy everything from my calculation tool there but that's one heck of a job and where is the guarantee this case will not happen again. I am wondering, is there something in particular Excel file settings that can be blocking `=WEBSERVICE` formula?

Comment: Well, you can try yourself `=WEBSERVICE("https://www.google.com/")` in Excel 2016 and see what you get. I am getting HTML code of page `"<!doctype html><html itemscope="""" itemtype=""http://schema.org/WebPage""` etc.

Comment: You are right. Tried it at home and there all `WEBSERVICE` requests work. Now, at work, for me `=WEBSERVICE("https://www.google.com/")` does not work as well as `=WEBSERVICE("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml")`. But `=WEBSERVICE("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml")` works. So at work there is a firewall used which denies direct access to some URIs from Excel application. Ask your IT adminitration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I have already wrote to IT administration but according to them they are not blocking anything. However I also think they are. We will investigate further and I will try to reply here once solution has been found.

Comment: I have the same symptoms, but I tried through my phone hotspot (4G, nothing to do with the work network, no restrictions) and get the same issue. #VALUE! for all WEBSERVICE requests in Excel from Office 365 - so very latest release version. I have tried creating a new key for BING maps, tried all the above examples to no avail. I referenced Microsoft XML, v6.0 in the VBA editor - are there any other requirements? The URL encoded for the Bing Maps request does generate xml successfully in browser, and copying it all into word tells me it's about 2,200 characters, within MS text string limit...