# WEBSERVICE function does not work on Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I have created a spreadsheet that pulls in data via the WEBSERVICE function.  This function was implemented in Excel 2013 so I was expecting that it should work on that version or newer, however, it doesn't.  We are accessing the data via a non-authenticated web service and the two computers (one with 2013 and one with 2016) are on the same network i.e. there shouldn't be any blocking issues.  2016 performs the retrieval and calculation flawlessly and 2013 resolves to a #VALUE! error without ever hitting the end point (nothing in the web service log).
The only other variable is that the 2013 Excel is running on Windows 7 and 2016 is on Windows 10.  We have tried different endpoints to see if that makes any difference and it seems that Excel 2013 (or at least that version on Windows 7 with the latest service pack) does not work.  This seems odd considering that the combination surely would have worked when this function was introduced.
Is there anyone out there who has any suggestions on what we could try?  We cant insist on Excel 2016 because the spreadsheet will go out to partner organisations.

Any help greatly appreciated!!!
Matt

Comment: Difficult to know why it's not working on Excel 2013 - it should be supported there.  Are you unable to get any endpoints to work?  Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179960/excel-webservice-formula-returns-value-error

Comment: I checked that link and it doesn't help unfortunately.  Endpoints work perfectly in Windows 10/Excel 2016 but not in Win7/Excel 2013.  My developer tried other end-points and was able to get a response, but not consistently.  It seems there is some other problem.  It's almost like it's timing out, but it never hits the end-point so difficult to know where it's falling down.  Really appreciate your response.

Comment: Are the clients and the endpoints on the same network?

Comment: Yes they are at present - everything within our domain for testing.  Thanks Tim!

Comment: Any firewall enabled on the Win7 PC's?  If Yes have you tried turning it off?

Comment: No firewall :-(

Comment: OK I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Thanks all the same Tim, much appreciated

Comment: One more - are you certain that the argument being passed to WEBSERVICE is the same across both platforms?  Are there other formulas embedded there?

Comment: Arguments are the same since it is the same spreadsheet being populated with the same data.  Calls in 2013 fail immediately (there are three separate services and they all fail in the same way as well).